# How i add text in a tag in e2e testing Angular Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

how i add content in

tag for e2e testing in protractor

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
   <p>
     <br type="_moz">
   </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

i try this but this is not working

```
var p = element(by.css('.cke_editable p'));
p.sendKeys('This is a peragraph tag');
```

Comment: What does mean _not working_? Can you provide error?

Comment: Did you used `browser.pause()` and tried to find it in console of browser `$('.cke_editable p')` ?

Comment: yes i use browser.pause()

Comment: Can't help you unless you create some plnkr with that html and editor to let me see what is actually going on there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is the body that's editable in this case - send keys to it:

```
var body = element(by.css('body.cke_editable'));
body.sendKeys('This is a paragraph tag');
```

A bigger problem though is that, since this is a *CKeditor - it's usually embedded in an `iframe`*. This is actually important for us - we need to let the webdriver know that we want to [switch into the context](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo) of the `iframe`:

```
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.css("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame")));

var body = element(by.css('body.cke_editable'));
body.sendKeys('This is a paragraph tag');
```

Comment: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("body.cke_editable") this error occur

Comment: @GurpreetSingh have you switched to the appropriate iframe?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh there could be, for instance, nested frames. Though, it all comes to wild guessing now - I don't see the HTML code of your page and cannot tell what is wrong for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94285/discussion-between-gurpreet-singh-and-alecxe).

Comment: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined.  This is occur @alecxe

Comment: @GurpreetSingh oops, fixed.

Comment: browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.css("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame"))); where i place this?

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded now this occur

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Please include the complete error traceback to the question.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh this is not the error traceback. Please edit the question and add the complete error traceback to it.