# How do I uncheck a checked checkbox with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

How can i unselect a selected checkbox in angular protractor?

```
<div ng-init="frm.for_all_trades = true">
       <input id="product-" class="css-checkbox ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" value="option1" ng-model="frm.for_all_trades" ng-checked="frm.for_all_trades" name="product_1" checked="checked">
       <label class="css-label checkbox-label radGroup1" for="product-"> All </label>
</div>
```

I use this code but this is not working. Error occur clickable element not found.

```
var chkbox = element(by.model('frm.for_all_trades'));
expect(chkbox.isSelected()).toBe(true); //this is working
chkbox.click(); //click method not worked
```

Comment: Do you have error like `element is not clickable at point ...`? If not - please insert your error text for details.

Comment: same error occur  'element is not clickable at point'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case - you have wrong `zIndex` of parent that is overlapping on your `checkbox`

Comment: in protractor configuration file

Comment: I don't know anything about `By.cssSelector(".cke_editable")`. Please use syntax sugar as `element(by.css('.cke_editable')) === $('.cke_editable')`

Comment: when i select element by model then element is not clickable at point occur And i follow your ans but nothing happand only change screen size.

Comment: Can you add `browser.pause()` before that `click()` and look are you able to see your desired checkbox?

Comment: So you able to see that `checkbox` when protractor is paused?

Comment: click method is correct or not for select or unselect check box ??

Comment: Yes, we are using `click()` on checkboxes as well.

Comment: Problem can be: a) multiply elements with such modell b) you have misspelled something. To check second try to use `$()`, find it by class and do next: `$('.unholy-checkbox').isPresent().then((answer) => {console.log(answer)})`

Comment: $('.className').click(); then error occur  "No element found using locator"

Comment: Confused. Ok, if `element` is present, and if it's displayed my last though is about `zIndex` that overlaying above checkbox so selenium can not click it and clicks on another thing.

Comment: i will check n thnx for help

Comment: at least I never had problem with clicking on checkboxes, selected by model etc., and currently got a bunch of such tests.

Comment: i think u ryt somthing overlay in checkbox thats why it not clickable

Comment: It can be checked easily in **Safary** browser - it's very sensitive to `zIndex`. In **Chrome** using inspector you can hover checkbox and see did it highlighted or something bigger overlapped its with highlighting.

Comment: u great sir a label tag overlaying on checkbox now i click on label tag and checkbox is unchecked thnkew :)

Comment: ove me a beer or V ;D

Comment: hey @Appeiron want ur help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519647/how-i-add-text-in-a-tag-in-e2e-testing-angular-protractor