# How i add text in iframe in e2e testing Protractor

Tags: angularjs, iframe, protractor

how i add text in p tag?

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 350px;"><span id="cke_44" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>
<iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, editor2" aria-describedby="cke_106" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
   <p>
     <br type="_moz">
   </p>
 </body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

i use this code but the give error

```
var p = element(by.css('.cke_editable p'));
p.sendKeys('This is a peragraph tag');
```

Comment: please past the error which you get there.

Comment: css does not look correct. It should be `.cke_editable > p`

Comment: nothing happn again same error occur no element found @PriyanshuShekhar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i add text in a tag in e2e testing Angular Protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519647/how-i-add-text-in-a-tag-in-e2e-testing-angular-protractor)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to switch to the iframe's page context to do this:

```
browser.switchTo().frame($('.cke_wysiwyg_frame'))

var p = element(by.css('.cke_editable p'));
p.sendKeys('This is a peragraph tag');

// switch back to the "parent page" context
browser.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` this error ocurr

Comment: According to the docs you have to specify an iframe index of a name/id attribute. See https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.TargetLocator.prototype.frame